# Detecting whether build_ext is building a Python extension with debug information

Tags: python, cython

I have a Python package that has a Cython extension. In my `setup.py` file, how can I tell whether `build_ext` or `bdist_wheel` were supplied with the `--debug` flag? I want to link against different libraries based on the debug flag.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up doing something fancy, and just added this to the top of the setup.py script:

```
DEBUG = '--debug' in sys.argv
```